# Scriptural reference mandating Joint application of Urdhvapundra and tripundra?

Tags: scripture, tilak, smarta

The Urdhvapundra tilaka and the tripundra tilaka both are validated by scriptural proofs of their own.

But my question is does any scripture actually allow one to don the urdhva pundra and tripundra together?

[image]

I have seen some Smārtas put on a combined version of Both Tilakas together and I want to know if it is a scripturally correct practice or not.